# Realtek Audio Console UWP - DTS effects section empty

Tags: realtek-hd-audio

The Realtek Audio Console UWP app on my ASUS FX505-DT running windows 11 is missing controls in the DTS section. Because of this I am unable to use the Audio Equalizer. What could be causing it and how to bring it back? Reinstalling the driver and console app - did Not help.
[image]